# making C# multicast DNS (MDNS) requests

Tags: c#, mdns

anyone know if there is a "nice" way do to MDNS requests in C# ?
I know that I can do DLL import of [dnsapi.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/ns-windns-mdns_query_request) but I didn't find any good examples of making MDNS request using this DLL.

Comment: Could this help you ? https://github.com/richardschneider/net-mdns

Comment: @Arcord I have seen this repo, the problem is that I need to do mDNS requests without any external repos like nugets or github. I know that I can do raw socket but I'm trying to avoid it for now.

Comment: Shoudn't you also avoid to use that DLL in that case ? :-) It's a little bit like a nuget package... the only difference is that you are either installing the dependency properly (nuget) or poorly (dll import). But yes you will have to use directly the socket if you want to implement it yourself.

Comment: did you look at the pinvoke example? http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dnsapi.DnsQuery